# How can slidedown multi element one after another whit a delay time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have any div with the same class . I selected them and iterate through them to slide down each element. I want to slide down the first element and delay the next slide.

It's code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var num = 0;
  $(".showcourse").each(function (index) {
    $(this).attr("id", "ID" + num);
    num++;
  });
  for (var I = 0; i < $(".showcourse").length; i++) {
    $("#ID" + i).slideDown(2000).delay(2000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the order of the `delay` and `slideDown` functions.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var num = 0;
  $(".showcourse").each(function (index) {
    $(this).attr("id", "ID" + num);
    num++;
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < $(".showcourse").length; i++) {
    $("#ID" + i).delay(i * 2000).slideDown(2000);
  }
});
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sygn/7c3y6nsh/4/)